# No Diskspace left - /root folder very large

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage

on my small homeserver running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS I have run out of diskspace on my system disk root partition for some reason. The device is a 128Gb SSD with the following status:

df -h:

```
Dateisystem                       Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
udev                               3,8G       0  3,8G    0% /dev
tmpfs                              769M     12M  757M    2% /run
/dev/mapper/wuerfelchen--vg-root    22G     21G  403M   99% /
tmpfs                              3,8G    8,0K  3,8G    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5,0M       0  5,0M    0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              3,8G       0  3,8G    0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          473M    246M  203M   55% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M    3,6M  508M    1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/wuerfelchen--vg-homes   87G    541M   82G    1% /home
tmpfs                              769M       0  769M    0% /run/user/1000
```

sudo du -hsx /* | sort -rh | head -n 40:

```
12G /root
3,7G    /usr
3,6G    /var
1,1G    /lib
485M    /home
260M    /opt
244M    /boot
125M    /home_old
16M /bin
14M /sbin
12M /run
12M /etc
132K    /tmp
32K /mnt
16K /media
16K /lost+found
8,0K    /snap
8,0K    /export
4,0K    /srv
4,0K    /lib64
4,0K    /dead.letter
```

So, I can see, the folder /root is using 12G of the total 22G partition size, but I can't access the folder. What data is kept inside there? Can I check that somehow?

Thanks for help in advance!

sandman

Comment: the /root directory holds user data for the root user. normally it should *never* reach that huge size (on my system it is only 2.3M). can you tell us what `sudo du -h /root` says?

Comment: /home is only 1% full of 82GB. Whoever root is (you maybe?) should store their files in their home directory and not /root.

Comment: Please add the output of `lsblk -fs; sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`. Are you using 18.10? [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/567730/349837) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/296172/349837) might help you. If you need to make some space you can use `ncdu`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo du -h /root
```

gives me the following:

```
root@wuerfelchen:/# sudo du -h /root 
8,0K    /root/.ssh
8,0K    /root/.config/Duplicati/control_dir_v2
12G /root/.config/Duplicati
12G /root/.config
8,0K    /root/.nano
12G /root
```

So there seems to be a bug with Duplicati... But I have no idea why duplicati is able to read and write to /root...

EDIT:
As Duplicati is running as a deamon, the default behaviour of duplicati is to store its backup database to `/root/.config/Duplicati`. The solution is to move the database to a different place:
https://forum.duplicati.com/t/how-to-change-the-local-database-file-location/1394

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have root access, so a simple `sudo bash` should get you a root shell and you can simply `cd /root` and `ls` to have a look. If you don't own the files in /root you should probably find out who does before moving them :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... It's getting strange somehow. There seem to be no files or direcotries in /root `root@wuerfelchen:/root# ls -l
insgesamt 0`

Comment: the files are all in hidden folders (first character is a '.'), so they won't show up without the -a flag to ls. ls -la will show you the hidden files.